# Nmap doesn't use the script supplied in argument

Tags: linux, nmap

I'm running under Kali Linux and I'm trying to run a script against a host in the lab. The command I'm entering and the output is:

```
root@kali-vm:~# nmap --script smb-enum-users.nse -p445 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-14 22:19 GMT
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.00067s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:0D:77:AD (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.47 seconds
```

As you can see I'm trying to get him to run the script "smb-enum-users.nse" on the target host. However Nmap seems to only be doing a quick scan on the given port instead of running the script.

**EDIT**
Should have maybe added that I know from a vuln. scan that it is possible to enumerate the users using smb on that target system.

Comment: Please run with `-d` and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use this script with microsoft windows family, the only way to find usernames in windows is to use bruteforce attack with programs such as acccheck. nmap smb-enum-users works with windows 2000 with null session and linux samba software as you can see below:

```
nmap --script smb-enum-users --script-args smbport=445,samronly=1,obj=1 192.168.1.99
```

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-18 18:08 IRDT
NSE: Script Scanning completed.
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.99
Host is up (0.0064s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Host script results:
| smb-enum-users:
|   KALI\graymind (RID: 1001)
|     Full name:
|     Description: 
|     Flags:       Normal user account
|   KALI\user (RID: 1000)
|     Full name:
|     Description: 
|_    Flags:       Normal user account

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds